# Тире или двоеточие?

Tags: пунктуация

Ставим ли мы двоеточие или тире в предложениях по типу:
"Как вам писать - на русском или на английском?"
"Какое это предложения - сложносочиненное или сложноподчиненное?"
"Какой вы человек - импульсивный или рассудительный?"
Мне почему-то ближе тире, однако я не могу найти никакого правила, подтверждающего мои догадки.

Answer (score 2):

Эти предложения простые, одноосновные, а слова после тире - уточняющие. Розенталь:

> § 22. Уточняющие члены предложения
> Обособляются (выделяются запятыми, реже — тире) слова и словосочетания, уточняющие смысл предшествующих слов (уточнение — это переход от более широкого понятия к более узкому).

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=118

Так что здесь лучше всего подойдёт запятая, допустимо тире, а двоеточие лучше не ставить.

Comment: Все-таки это уточнение, я так и предполагал, спасибо за ответ.

Comment: @sergey-slepov А что если далее следует перечисление из более чем двух вариантов?

Comment: @boldnik, если смотреть по правилам, то ничего особо не меняется, если у нас нет сочинительных союзов, то ставим запятую между всеми уточняющими членами, т.к. они однородны. Если же первый член без союза, а остальные с союзом, то ставим запятые между всеми членами опять, это тоже следует из правил обособления однородных членов предложения 
         http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=73                                                        
           http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=118             Нередко уточняющие обстоятельства места выстраиваются в ряд, образуют цепочку